# Application connect to container directly

Tags: networking, docker, containers

May be this is a common question in docker technology stack.

Say suppose we have

```
1. A client application "A" running on a host IPAddressA, 
2. A docker container host with IPAddressB
  2.1 An server "S" running as a container on above container host with IPAddressC.
```

What should be done to make sure that client Application 'A' can talk to server 'S' running on container with IPAddressC ?

Note : I did try using -p option (port forwarding) when spinning a new docker container. But then https on client application will fail due to which SSL certificate obtained is from docker container host rather container itself.